# VMware Fusion VM resolution not changeable from 800x600

Tags: display, vmware

I wondered if I ask this on either Mac community, or that of Ubuntu or else. But I hope Mac is the best one.

On Ubuntu in "Systems Setting" --> "Display", I only see 800x600 resolution option. As I change the size of the VM window, it just expands/shrink accordingly, maintaining the same ratio (800x600) that is way too narrow for me.

Already tried but no good:

- On VM's setting --> "Display", I tried checking both on/off with "Accelerate 3D Graphics" or "User full resolution for Retina display".
- Add `pref.autoFitGuestToWindow = "FALSE"` to ~/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/preferences (https://communities.vmware.com/message/2342718)
- Re-install VMWare Tools ([link](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525))
- Ubuntu DEB package open-vm-tools, along with [the instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools)

Any idea is appreciated.

- VMWare Fusion 6.0.3 with VMWare Tools installed (via [VMWare host](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools)).
- OSX 10.9.3 on Macbook Pro, Retina 15-inch
- VM: Ubuntu 12.04 64b

Comment: Try to reinstall VMware Tools if you haven't already. See <http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525>.

Comment: Make sure that Ubuntu **is** using the vmware drivers otherwise it will not work. Any recent release should have automatically autodetected it...

Comment: As I updated my OP, yeah I already tried re-install VMWare Tools (now I did it again) but no luck (btw what's your account name? It's not really shown).

Comment: @Vic Could you tell how to make sure that my Ubuntu is using VMWare drivers? I thought about it, but other than installing `vmwate-tools` I don't know how to do so.

Comment: IsaacS, take a look at this link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system