# VMWare Fusion Full-Screen Not Available

Tags: macos, mojave, vmware

I'm running Mojave on my MacBook Pro. IT-support installed VMWare Fusion but I can't expand the VMware Fusion window to the full width of my laptop. It's really frustrating. Any ideas on how to fix?

I saw [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135573/vmware-fusion-vm-resolution-not-changeable-from-800x600) for Ubuntu but that's not my OS.

[image: Mac]

Additionally - is there a setting to enable my windows VM to run full screen on macOS Mojave?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install VMware tools inside the Windows virtual machine to be to resize the resolution of the virtual machine from the host. That will enable you to resize the window to fit the width of your display, as well as being able to enable "Resize to Fit" so that when you resize the size of the window, the virtual display resolution within the virtual machine changes as well.

You can install VMware Tools by opening the menu titled "Virtual Machine" and choosing "Install VMware Tools".

Without VMware Tools you'll need to change the resolution of the virtual machine from within the virtual machine itself. On Windows you'll often be able to do so by right-clicking the Desktop and selecting Properties, and then select a display resolution that matches the width of your display. It is not that convenient.

If you want to run the virtual machine in full screen, i.e. not in a window, you can do so by opening the menu titled "View" and choosing "Full Screen". Or as a keyboard shortcut, press Ctrl-Cmd-F.

Comment: @user3439894 Noone has said that it is required. I don't know where you got that misconception.

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, that is correct - you need to install VMware Tools to be able to resize the window to fit the width of the display, which is what I wrote. When you go to Full Screen you're no longer resizing a window.

Comment: Thanks you @jksoegaard. I installed the VM tools but I my magic command is still greyed out.

https://i.imgur.com/undefined.png

Comment: @philsimon There's something wrong with your image url? - What do you mean by "magic command"?

Comment: The command that lets me go to full screen.

I think that it's because I'm not an admin on my work computer.

Comment: [jksoegaard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/77912/jksoegaard) has the right answer, installing VMware Tools. I'll just add that your VM machine must be powered on and logged in, or else the VMware Tools option is greyed out. This had me tripped up for a while. It's because the VMware Tools actually mounts a disk onto your VM like a CD, and installs from there. It's not installed on the host OS like I thought. Don't have enough reputation to add this as a comment though.